# DJANGO - Show PIN only if SIM is selected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

En el formulario en modo admin: ¿Cómo mostrar el input pin sólo cuando en type se selecciones SIM?

Ejemplo:

```
DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Datalogger'),
        ('1','Radar'),
        ('2','Modem'),
        ('3','SIM'),
    )
type = models.CharField('TipoDispositivo', max_length=1, choices=DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICE,null=True)
if type == "SIM":
    pin = models.CharField('PIN',max_length=100,null=True)
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta al español, ya llevas bastante tiempo en el SO, asi que ya deberias saberlo.

Comment: Perdona, pensaba que estaba en la english versión. Lo modifico.

Comment: No hay problema, por otra parte, quieres que se muestre el campo `pin` cuando `type` sea `SIM`, ¿Lo quieres hacer en "tiempo real" por asi decirlo (que habria que utilisar JavaScript)? O quieres por ejemplo, crear la instancia, y al momento de editar dicha instancia, si el campo `type` es `SIM`, mostrar el campo `pin` (esta opcion seria mucho mas sencilla)?

Comment: Tiempo real. ¿Se puede utilizar javascript o Ajax en admin? ¿O soló en el template?

Comment: Creo que si, de hecho se puede inyectar codigo CSS en el admin, si se puede inyectar codigo CSS, debe ser posible inyectar codigo JavaScript. (habria que investigar, ademas de que debes saber la estructura del form, para utilisar JavaScript).

Comment: El codigo se inyecta atraves del form.

Comment: Si se puede, echale un vistaso a la [doc de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions), ahi se explica como hacerlo. Por otra parte leyendo la doc me encontre con algo interesante, se pueden anular las plantillas del admin, esto te puede ayudar tambien, [doc de Django sobre la anulacion de plantillas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)